# RegEx expression using Positive Lookbehind

Tags: regex

I am trying to develop a regex expression to extract the address, sale date and sale price information from this string:

```
<strong id="address">1245 DUPONT ST</strong><br>Toronto : Metro Toronto<br>14 Aug 2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$71,000,000&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#CC0000"></font>
```

Ideally, I would like to receive the information formatted on five separate rows like this:

```
1245 DUPONT ST  
Toronto  
Metro Toronto  
14 Aug 2015  
$71,000,000
```

I suspect that the solution will involve the use of [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) because the address information can always by identified by the `id="address"`, but I can't seem to get it working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using uBot, which is a kind of windows automation software.  Not really sure of the underlying basis in which it is programmed.

Comment: is this information comming always in the same order?

Comment: Yes @Fede, always in the same order, and always with a full-colon separating the lower tier-municipality (Toronto), from the upper-tier municipality (Metro Toronto).

Comment: Apparently uBot is written in C# and will work with the .Net regular expression engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree on having a regex to parse xml and would use a html parser instead.

However, for your specific example I can come up with this regex that works on PCRE engine:

```
id="address">(.*?)<|<br>(.*?) : (.*?)<br>|(?<=<br>)(.*?)&|(\$[^&]+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eY6cW2/1)**

Match information:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [21-35] `1245 DUPONT ST`
MATCH 2
2.  [48-55] `Toronto`
3.  [58-71] `Metro Toronto`
MATCH 3
4.  [75-86] `14 Aug 2015`
MATCH 4
5.  [122-133]   `$71,000,000`
```

Comment: Wow, that indeed does work.  Amazing stuff @Fede.  Why do you say that you disagree with using regex to parse XML?  I don't understand anything about what a regex parser is.  Perhaps I should read-up on that.

Comment: @DanielAttard you might want to see this question with it's accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4464702 He's also trying to regex-match in HTML.

Comment: @DanielAttard you can use regex to parse xhtml **only** if you know what the characters set is, in that case regex is not a bad solution. However, if you use xml then XPath, XQuery are the right approach, on the other hand if you use html then html parsers are a good choice. Anyway, if you don't want to involve a new framework or library, then a simple regex might do the trick.